# "InvalidOperationException" error showing values from model in ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to show values in table from controller to view using model but it shows an error. I have debugged and checked values are returned OK, but the code shows an error. I don't know where is problem please let me know how can I resolve/fix this issue?

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class RoomsStatus
{
    [Key]

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckInDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOutDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal DailyPricePerBed { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfBeds { get; set; }
    public string PriceType { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationDbConext:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<RoomsStatus> RSN { get; set; }
 }
```

**RoomsController:**

```
//view booking details and rooms status
public async Task<IActionResult> RoomsStatus(int PartnerID,int BuldingID)
{
        try
        {
            return this.View("RoomsStatus", await _context.RSN.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetRoomsStatusByID {0},{1}", PartnerID, BuldingID).ToListAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Logger.LogError(e, "Error while displaying booking.");
            return this.RedirectToAction("Error", "Base");
        }
}
```

**RoomStatus** view:

```
@model IEnumerable<FewoVerwaltung.Models.RoomsStatus>

<h1>RoomsStatus</h1>

 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And this is the error I get:

> Stack InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[FewoVerwaltung.Models.RoomsStatus]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FewoVerwaltung.Models.Base.BaseModel'

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining unexpected type of View Model has been passed to the View.

It's expecting `FewoVerwaltung.Models.Base.BaseModel`,

but got `List<FewoVerwaltung.Models.RoomsStatus>`

### Check List

1. #### Model Type

   I see model type has been declared in the view

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<FewoVerwaltung.Models.RoomsStatus>
   ```

   But the error shows that it's not picking up the model type declared, so I would try recompiling the project, make sure it's running the latest project code.
2. #### View file location

   Make sure the View file `RoomsStatus.cshtml` is in folder `~/Views/Rooms/`

   ```
   ~/Views/Rooms/RoomsStatus.cshtml
   ```
3. #### Controller route

   Make sure the URL, assuming it's

   ```
   http://localhost:{int}/Rooms/RoomsStatus?PartnerID={int}&BuldingID={int}
   ```

   is handled by the `RoomsController` Controller

Comment: Hi thanks for response, i have check your all above mentioned things and all are ok and URL look like this when i click on table row from another controller,actually i am calling this controller and action on row click in another controller view.After click on `row` url look like this `https://localhost:44334/Rooms/RoomsStatus?PartnerID=1&BuldingID=11` but issue is same error occured, i am using `baseController` and `BaseModel` as well , so what changes i need to do in baseController and `BaseModel` actually i am new and doing changes in existing project, old developer left this project,